# Updating LibreOffice Calc 3.3.4

Tags: libreoffice

good day!

how do I update from calc 3.3.4 to 3.5? I couldn't find a button or option in the program that was related to updates. :(

is there no alternative to uninstalling the whole thing and installing the newer version?

Comment: Please add more information. What is your ubuntu version? Did you installed it manually or it was pre-installed?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to update a single package is to look for a PPA (Personal Package Archive). These are hosted on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) and it allows users to package and distribute newer versions of packages. See [these instructions for adding a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them).

[Here is a PPA for LibreOffice](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa) with 3.5.x for 11.10. Although to be sure to read the notes on the PPA page that says that the packages are for testing. Most likely you'll be fine, but caveat emptor.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to tick the box next to this answer to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

In general it is enough to uninstall (using Ubuntu Software Center) Libre Office, and download the version for linux from the website. All You need is described in the README files in downloaded packages. It integrates with Ubuntu very well, and automatically :]

Comment: but if it was pre-installed as a part of ubuntu it should get updated automatically with update manager. isn't it?

Comment: MAybe, I've never tried that way,because usually it corrupts apt, as far as I had experience with updating.

Comment: i guess that might be the only option we have :( thank you! we don't plan on updating ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to reinstalling the entire program would be to upgrade to 12.04, and have the LibreOffice Calc package automatically updated to 3.5.2, which [already appears in the Precise repos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libreoffice-calc). This is better than reinstalling LibreOffice if you plan on updating to 12.04 already.

Comment: unfortunately, we are not considering updating to 12.04 :( but, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you did install the current version manually, you don't need to uninstall it before installing the new version (manually, too). Just download the tar.gz. archives, extract them and install the .deb files und `sudo spkg -i *.deb` in the `/DEBS` subdirectory of the extracted archives.